# ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function Visual Studio Code Terminal

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, terminal, ng-build

In Visual Studio Code, when I am running command `ng build`, I am getting this error:

```
PS D:\Dashboard\Test1> ng build
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng build
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have added these environment variables in `Path`:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Users\Avind\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Users\Avind\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

How can I get rid of this issue?

Note: I have `node.js` in `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. From the command prompt, `ng new project` is not working, but it is working from a `node.js` command.

After executing `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` from the Visual Studio Code terminal, I am getting the below message and the `ng` command is not working:

```
PS D:\Path\Test1> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
C:\Users\Avind\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\Avind\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@9.1.9 postinstall C:\Users\AR20095474\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@9.1.9
updated 1 package in 53.477s
```

Comment: What does `npm config get bin-links` return if u execute it in your terminal?

Comment: @kai - In VS code terminal saying `true`.

Comment: Can u also check that inside `C:\Users\Avind\AppData\Roaming\npm` there is a file called `ng.cmd`?

Comment: @kai - Yes this file is there in the same path.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to install the latest [Angular CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) to make the 'ng' command work. You can run it from the command terminal or Visual Studio Code terminal:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

If it is still not working, uninstall and reinstall Node.js from *Programs and Features*.

Comment: interesting you have node  and npm installed? you ran it as administrator?

Comment: I have node.js and npm as given above env variable pl check. I ran above cmd as admin still VS code showing error.

Comment: i can clearly see angular cli installed, i think you are doing something silly

Comment: And that silly I have been doing since yesterday. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: may be try to execute that in command prompt and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216465/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-arvind-chourasiya).

Answer (score 9):

As here [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io), make sure you installed Angular CLI.
You can run this command from anywhere on your system.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng --version
```

It should print something like this:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 13.1.2
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1301.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         13.1.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.1.2 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          13.1.2 (cli-only)
```

Comment: From where do I need to execute it?

Comment: anywhere not important, it's global install.

Comment: After doing it, I am able to create project from cmd but VS code still not running ng command.

Comment: if u not close the vs code after install CLI, try restarting. and show your result

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. Trying previous answers did not work in my case.

Run this command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Reference:

*[ng : File \AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file npm\ng.ps1 is not digitally signed Angular Error when running commands](http://www.techtutorhub.com/article/Getting-ng-File-AppData-Roaming-npm-ng-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-The-file-npm-ng-ps1-is-not-digitally-signed-Angular-Error-when-running-commands/62)*

Answer (score 4):

I received a similar error while working with PowerShell, and I used the following command to resolve it:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

Step 1: Run the command "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser"

When you run this command, you can see that your system has set all policies for the current user as remotely. It will take few seconds to complete this process.

Step 2: *Enter image description here*

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
```

When you run this command, a few policies are shown on your monitor screen.

Verify if the policy for the current user is RemoteSigned.
If yes, this it should work now. If no, please try method 2 as below:

Method 2:

Find the file "ng.ps1" in path C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\ and
remove it from the directory.

If you don't know the file extension, then right-click on the file -> go to *Properties* and check the extension of file.

Note: Please do not remove any other file. Make sure you are removing the *ng.ps1* file only.

Comment: Removing ng.ps1 seems to force the file to be recreated, this time with the proper signature. That seems a lot safer than fiddling with policy.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Then use the following:

1. Open Windows PowerShell
2. Run

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
   Get-ExecutionPolicy
   ```

   and you get

   ```
   RemoteSigned
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
   ```

   You get

   ```
   Scope          ExecutionPolicy
   -----          ---------------
   MachinePolicy  Undefined
   UserPolicy     Undefined
   Process        Undefined
   CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
   LocalMachine   Undefined
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I reopened CMD in a new tab and typed the same thing like this:

```
ng g c componentname
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to the *Path* environment variable not being set.

This worked for me:

Run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After installing, you enter *Advanced System Configuration* → *Environment Variables* → *Path* → *Edit*.

If this Angular variable is not in the path, you add:
"C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\npm"

Close the terminal, open it and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just running these three commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

It worked.

Comment: But not "`or`" (isn't literal?)? Can you make that clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Four steps to fix:

1. Uninstall Node.js and
2. Go to website: https://nodejs.org/en/
3. Reinstall with the latest LTS<sup>[1]</sup> (see image below)

   [image]
4. Finally, try the accepted answer above again.

<sup>[1]: LTS stands for long term support</sup>